# "NoneType" object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Я работаю над созданием игры для Discord бота с использованием библиотеки disnake. В игре предполагается использование интерактивных кнопок. Однако возникла ошибка **"NoneType" object has no attribute 'id'**, которая появляется в моем коде в строке, где я использую **wait_for** для прослушивания нажатий на кнопки. Я неоднократно проверил свой код и импорты, и все кажется правильным. Я не понимаю, почему возникает эта ошибка. Не могли бы вы предоставить совет по тому, как устранить эту проблему и найти её источник?

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.ui import Button
import random
import asyncio

class BottleCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.game_data = {}

    @commands.slash_command(
        name="bottle",
        description="Игра в бутылочку",
    )
    async def bottle(self, ctx):
        if ctx.guild.id in self.game_data:
            await ctx.send("Игра уже идет на этом сервере.")
            return

        self.game_data[ctx.guild.id] = {"players": [], "running": False}

        buttons = [
            Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, label="Участвовать"),
            Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red, label="Закончить набор"),
            Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, label="Закончить игру")
        ]

        view = disnake.ui.View()
        for button in buttons:
            view.add_item(button)

        message = await ctx.send("Поиграем в бутылочку?", view=view)

        while True:
            try:
                def check(interaction):
                    return interaction.message.id == message.id and interaction.user.id != self.bot.user.id

                interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", timeout=30, check=check)
                
                player_id = interaction.user.id

                if interaction.component.label == "Участвовать":
                    self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]["players"].append(player_id)
                    await interaction.response.send_message("Вы участвуете в игре!")

                elif interaction.component.label == "Закончить набор":
                    if player_id == ctx.author.id:
                        self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]["running"] = True
                        await interaction.response.send_message("Набор завершен. Игра началась!")

                elif interaction.component.label == "Закончить игру":
                    if player_id == ctx.author.id:
                        del self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]
                        await interaction.response.send_message("Игра завершена. Данные удалены.")
                        await message.delete()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                break

        if self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]["running"]:
            if len(self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]["players"]) >= 2:
                chosen_players = random.sample(self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]["players"], 2)
                await ctx.send(f"Бутылочка выбрала игроков: <@{chosen_players[0]}> и <@{chosen_players[1]}>!")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Недостаточно игроков для начала игры.")

            del self.game_data[ctx.guild.id]

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(BottleCog(bot))
```

Менял код уже с десяток раз, одна и та же ошибка. Также забыл упомянуть, что испоьзую систему когов, поэтому код такой неполноценный.
ошибка возникает в двух строчках:

```
return interaction.message.id == message.id and interaction.user.id != self.bot.user.id
```

и

```
interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click", timeout=30, check=check)
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное Вам стоит делать проверку на возврат этого метода. Можно например так:

```py
interaction = await self.bot.wait_for(...)
if interaction is None:
     return None
```

Потому что есть вероятность, что данный метод может возвращать None, поэтому стоит предусмотреть вариант исхода событий когда функция вернула None.

Я смогу более подробно ответить на Ваш вопрос если вы предоставите код метода `self.bot.wait_for()`